# Is the mapping in solidity of one key on multiple structs of same type possible?

Tags: struct, mapping, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to map one address on multiple structs of same type, which belongs to the same address. How can I do this, if I want to choose any of the "stored" structs for one address on request afterwards?

I created a struct called Prescription, and a mapping with the patients address. So what I really want is to map the patients address to several Prescription-structs.

```
struct Prescription {
    address patients_address;
    string medicament;
    string dosage_form;
    uint amount;
    uint date;
}

mapping (address => Prescription) ownerOfPrescription;

address [] public patients;

function createPrescription(address patients_address, string medicament, string dosage_form, uint amount, uint date) public restricted {
    var newPrescription = ownerOfPrescription[patients_address];

    newPrescription.medicament = medicament;
    newPrescription.dosage_form = dosage_form;
    newPrescription.amount = amount;
    newPrescription.date = date;

    patients.push(patients_address) -1;
}

function getPre(address _address)view public returns (string, string, uint, uint){ 
    return( 
        ownerOfPrescription[_address].medicament, 
        ownerOfPrescription[_address].dosage_form, 
        ownerOfPrescription[_address].amount, 
        ownerOfPrescription[_address].date);
}
```

Now I would have a function, where I can call all written Prescriptions for one patient. Actually I am able to call only the last written prescription for one address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the value type of a `mapping` can be an array:

```
// map to an array
mapping (address => Prescription[]) ownerOfPrescription;

function createPrescription(...) ... {
     // add to the end of the array
     ownerOfPrescription[patients_address].push(Prescription({
         medicament: medicament,
         ...
     });

     patients.push(patients_address);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great help smarx. Now I have other issues with retrieving data from the stored structures I made. I think for this I have to create a new question (because it´s not allowed as an answer here :) )

Comment: to reterieve data. you have to do it in a way that in the distributted application first you have to find the total length of the data and then you have to create a for loop to reterive them one by one

Comment: Yea but it did not function when I tried a function like: function getOverview(address patients_address) public view restricted returns(Prescription[]) {
        require(patientInList[patients_address]);
        uint[] memory index = indicies[patients_address];
        Prescription [] memory overview = new Prescription[](index.length);

        for(uint i = index[0]; i<index.length; i++) {

            overview[i] = prescriptions[i];
                   }
        return (overview);
    }

Comment: What I mean is that I whether could return an array of structs or array of strings. I read in several tasks, that it is still not possible in solidity. The only solution seems to be to return the struct-components individually. If there are any updates on this topic, I would be very grateful for a hint.

Comment: Hi @user94559 I follow these steps but I got error the second time I tried to push...